# Multiplication of a vector by an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, products

I have a question, consider $V$ an orthogonal matrix, and $u$ and $z$ are vectors, and W is a matrix does :

$V'u = W V'z  \implies   u = W z$ ?

I want to get rid of the orthogonal matrix $V'$, my intuition says that I can, but I don't know which property of the orthogonal matrices will help me to do say.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think WZ is a scalar, while U is a vector. So they cannot be equal.

Comment: no it's not a scalar, it's a vector

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $V'u = WV'z$, we have

$$V'(u - Wz) = (WV' - V'W) z.$$

For the left-hand side to be zero for arbitrary $z$, $W$ and $V'$ have to commute, so your statement is not true in general.

Comment: yes, my matrices do commute ! thank you for your answer, although i didn't fully understand why this equality is true :

Comment: this one V'(u - Wz) = (WV' - V'W) z.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it: if $V'$ and $W$ commute, then $V'u=WV'z$ if and only if $V'u=V'Wz$ if and only if ${V'}^{\dagger}V'u={V'}^{\dagger}V'Wz$ if and only if $u=Wz.$